# Which risks after a chown on /usr/local/

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, local

First of all sorry for my english I'm french. I was trying to install `rvm` on OS X El Capitan, and an error stopped the installation, said me to check that `brew update` run correctly and surprise, it don't include with `sudo`. Few days ago while El Capitan finish install, I run the native disk analyser to restore broken things (S.O.S button). When I was with Yosemite I think `[sudo] brew update` works.

Anyway, `sudo chown -R myname:admin /usr/local/` and I got what I want. But which risks did I expose myself by execute that command on this directory on my personnal computer or on a remote server that I own ?

Independent question, is it a good idea to do a `git revert` on a commit of that chown ? I mean the directory was first mixed with different owners, the `chown -R` messed up.

Comment: This first part of this question is on-topic for SO because it is a specific question about a tool ("rvm) used almost exclusively by developers.  The second, independent question should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

First your english is good enough. And understand most of people on StackExchange are not native english speakers.

However try to be more clear. Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you.

Else very quick answer:

- `sudo chown -R myname:admin /usr/local/` is bad. Let the system manage this part.
- if you can `git revert`, do